# Vertical overflow not expected on flex basis

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have the following code:

```js
export default function Home() {
  const lists = ["List A", "List B", "List C", "List D"]

  return (
    <div className="flex gap-3">
      {lists.map(list => {
        return <div key={list} className="grow-0 shrink-0 basis-80 bg-red-200">{list}</div>
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The width of each list must be fixed at 20rem (basis-80) and it is working. If I add to many lists, as expected, an horizontal scrollbar is created. But what I do not understand is why, when there is an horizontal overflow, also there is is a vertical overflow. Like we can see on the images, the lists are taking just a fraction of the vertical space.

No horizontal overflow
[image: No overflow]

Both axis overflow, but I was only expecting an horizontal overflow.
[image: Overflow]

Answer (score 0):

One way to get rid of the vertical overflow is to set the `overflow-y` property of the container element to hidden. This will prevent the vertical scrollbar from appearing.

You can try adding `overflow-y: hidden;` to the CSS of the container element.

Comment: It works, but why the behavior is happening?

Comment: That's because the horizontal scrollbar also takes space in your DOM